# Iterating through a vector without begin and end

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of keywords and I need to iterate through it.

My attempt :

```
bool isKeyword(string s)
{
  return find(keywords, keywords + 10, s ) != keywords + 10;
}
```

however this works for an array but not for a vector. How can I change the + 10 to iterate through the vector? I need this since I can't use end and begin because I do not have C++11 support.

Error given for the above code:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::size_type, std::string&)'|
```

Comment: `keywords.begin()`. You don't need C++11 for that. Why the +10, though?

Comment: @dlf, Presumably the current array has 10 elements. Anyway, it's easy to make your own free versions of `begin` and `end` if you don't have C++11.

Comment: Look at this excellent reference regarding vector: [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  You will find that `begin()` and `end()` and the respective iterators have been supported long before C++11's release.

Comment: @chris your comment implies that `begin` and `end` require `C++11`. I guess this is not what you intended.

Comment: @G.Samaras, My comment implies that the **free** versions of `begin` and `end` require C++11. Your inferred meaning was not my implication.

Comment: @chris I think is good that you cleared that out, so that other (un -experienced, like me) users do not get confused. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `begin()` and `end()` like this:

```
find(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), s )
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // std::find

using namespace std;

bool isKeyword(string& s, std::vector<string>& keywords)
{
  return (find(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), s ) != keywords.end());
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string s = "Stackoverflow";
    v.push_back(s);
    if(isKeyword(s, v))
        cout << "found\n";
    else
        cout << "not found\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As others state, you do not need `C++11` for this application.

Ref, of [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Comment: Why pass `string s` by value when no copy is ever needed?

Comment: I just copy pasted the prototype of the OP. Nice point, I will edit @C.R.

Comment: Further nitpicking, the reference should be `const` or you won't be able to pass temporaries to it.